# Using DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql,params) with a generic type

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlclient

I'm finding myself using a very similar set of code over and over for different stored procedues

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = {
  new SqlParameter("@somevar", 123),
  new SqlParameter("@othervar", 456)
}
List<MyClass> result;
using (MyContext contextName = new MyContext())
{
  result = contextName.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("mystoredproc @somevar, @othervar", parameters).ToList();
}
```

And I thought to myself, why not make a standard set of code that passes in the stored procedure and SqlParameter[]

MyClass result = getStoredProcResult("mystoredproc", parameters);

Where I'm struggling is making SqlQuery generic.

I tried using

```
result = contextName.Database.SqlQuery<object>(procname, parameters);
```

However, I always just get an object out, and it will not return  back to MyClass
I tried using Type, but get an error with that..

Is there something I'm missing, or can it just not handle a generic class and I'm doomed to just repeat myself?

Comment: Don't reinvent the Dapper.

Comment: I've never thought of using Dapper tbh. Will give that a look over now. thanks

Comment: Well, I wasted a lot of time and effort when I should have just been using Dapper.  @AlexanderPetrov - thank you.  If you want to put that as the answer I'd be happy to mark it as such.

Comment: This is on the list of EF 8 changes.  In EF 7, you have to have an entity defined in order to do it.